# Marking a Cocoa document-based document as dirty

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I am following the Core Data example given by Cocoa® Programming for Mac® OS X, Third Edition in Chapter 11. I am having problems with not being able to save the document until the application closes.

I can enter car details fine; graphics, fine. The red dot in the corner of the window remains red without the black dot, which to me means the document is clean even though I have made several changes to it. Also, the Save and Save As menu items are disabled.

The only way I can get to save the document is to close the application, whereupon it asks "Are you sure?" and I can go ahead and save and reload without any problems.

I've combed through the bindings in the book to make sure I haven't missed anything but this is bugging me because I know very little about Core Data and am trying to learn it. I can't even get the tutorials right!

Comment: [This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started) is a good tutorial on core data.

Answer (score 0):

> I can enter car details fine;
>   graphics, fine. The red dot in the
>   corner of the window remains red
>   without the black dot, which to me
>   means the document is clean even
>   though I have made several changes to
>   it. Also, the Save and Save As menu
>   items are disabled.

the save being commented out typically means that you don't have something in your responder chain that responds to save:. Are you starting with a document based app? That starts with the ability, if not you will need to implement save:

you will probably bring up a save dialog and invoke one of NSManagedObject contexts save to file methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Grady. I've sorted it out now - I hadn't connected the File Owner to the window.